# Setting spatial precision in Mysql

Tags: mysql, floating-point, geospatial, precision

For my application I have to store coordinates ,so I decided to use POINT type. My app only needs precision up to 4 digits so the question is: Can I change the precision of a POINT or could I use something else to store my data in (I need SPATIAL INDEXes)? Or should I just ignore the fact that it uses lot of space for nothing?

Edit: I need it for a tile based game. Where tiles are 0.0001 apart.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think database space is an issue.

Also, someone might decide to up the needed precision so you'll be glad you have it.